# AWS SDK CryptProtectData failed

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am using aws sdk for .net, creating a pig activity in an emr cluster and calling in a pipeline,

```
try
{
    var profileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWS_PROFILE_NAME"];
    var accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"];
    var secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWS_SECRET_KEY"];

    Amazon.Util.ProfileManager.RegisterProfile(profileName, accessKey, secretKey);

    using (_dataPipelineClient = new AmazonDataPipelineClient(accessKey, secretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
    {
        //proccesing code ...
    }    
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.Error("ReportScheduler -> Error ocurred.", e);
    throw new Exception("ReportScheduler -> Error ocurred.", e);
}
```

in my local server it has no problem everything run perfectly. But in the hosting it throw this exception :

AmazonClientException

CryptProtectData failed.

```
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Settings.UserCrypto in Encrypt at line 94:0
    System.String Encrypt(System.String)

Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Settings.SettingsCollection+ObjectSettings in WriteToJson at line 94:0
    Void WriteToJson(ThirdParty.Json.LitJson.JsonWriter)

Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Settings.SettingsCollection in Persist at line 62:0
    Void Persist(System.IO.StreamWriter)

Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Settings.PersistenceManager in saveSettingsType at line 93:0
    Void saveSettingsType(System.String, Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Settings.SettingsCollection)

Amazon.Util.ProfileManager in RegisterProfile at line 115:0
    Void RegisterProfile(System.String, System.String, System.String)
```

Can someone give me some idea, about where could be the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and what worked for me was to use basic AWS credentials instead of using store ones.

```
    public static AmazonS3Client GetAwsS3Client(string accessKey, string secretKey)
    {
        var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

        return new AmazonS3Client(credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
    }
```

Comment: The `RegisterProfile` approach is also discouraged by Amazon: https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx3VJIHQF8Q0YSX/RegisterProfile